# QComboBox , tabviews, C++

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing an application with tabviews.
I want that tabView to change the widget depending on the ComboBox choice.
ex: if the first index chosen I want tabView1 to appear
if the second index chosen I want tabView2 to appear
I tired few methods, if(str == "a") layout->tabview1; else layout->tabView2.
I also tried the connect(combobox,SIGNAL(currentTextChanged()),this,SIGNAL(swithcall()))
one of the main problems I can't do much instructions in swticahll function because in that case I will have to identify the tabviews as global variables which is not the best choice.
Any recommendations?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambdas inside a connect line,
ex:

```
connect(combobox,&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged,this,[tabView](int index) mutable{
// change tabView as wanted
});
```

If you want to change by text and index (not just index like here), you can use (inside the lambda):

```
QString currText = combobox->currentText();
```

Comment: Ca marche bien cette solution d'un coté ,  par contre je veux aussi de revenir à la tabView de base quant on rechange le choix du ComboBox

Answer (score 0):

You can just connect `QComboBox`'s signal `currentIndexChanged` to `QTabWidget`'s `setCurrentIndex` slot like `connect(combobox, &QComboBox::cutrentIndexChanged, tabview, &QTabWidget::setCurrentIndex)`, and add widgets to your `tabview` in the required order that corresponds to items order in your `combobox`.